# please help solve 'oracle-java7-installer' missing; dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic

Tags: installation, uninstall

system info

Linux -System-Product-Name 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP  i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please avoid posting the same question twice. Instead, you can edit your original question to add new information. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the solution thanks to  -Projjol                                                                                                                       You have a package that was not installed correctly or is broken. You have to remove linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.

I would suggest that you use the following code: gksudo nautilus /var/lib/dpkg/info Now find all files starting with names linux-headers-3.8.0-19 and delete them. Then:

    sudo apt-get -f install

    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

    sudo apt-get install linux

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution thanks to  -Projjol
You have a package that was not installed correctly or is broken. You have to remove linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.

I would suggest that you use the following code: gksudo nautilus /var/lib/dpkg/info Now find all files starting with names linux-headers-3.8.0-19 and delete them. Then:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install linux
```